# Sequential analysis - adjusting effect size

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, sequential-analysis, optimal-stopping, stopping-time

I am aware that sequential testing is risky, but it makes sense for me to do it anyway. So, I would like to read up, to do it properly.

My idea (which is probably not new):

In my reality, the true effect in a hypothesis test sometimes exceeds the minimum effect size by a large margin. So, to be more efficient with resources, I intend to test with a high hypothesized effect size in a Neyman-Pearson framework. Then, only if I fail to show the high effect size, I reduce the hypothesized effect size to some level that I determined before starting the experiment, and collect more data as needed to achieve the desired power. I repeat this until I reach the minimum effect size that I'm trying to determine.

Now, of course, my tests are no longer independent, so the usual calculations of the Type I and II error rates become invalid. I think that the changes in hypothesized effect size should counteract at least some of this, but I'm basically just guessing that - and guesswork isn't very Neyman-Pearson-like ;)

I find it difficult to find an entry point into this field of study, since I don't know the terminology yet, so I don't know what to look for. I have done a quick search, and found some general information on Wald, Pocock and Haybittle-Peto. It seems that these strategies were developed to preserve $\alpha$ in an effect-size agnostic Fisherian framework (if I haven't misinterpreted it). That's a little different from what I dreamed up.

So, what is the name of what I need to look for? What's a good book to start with?
(or, is there a fundamental flaw in my idea?)

Comment: Good question. Ast you are testing multiple hypotheses, this requires adjustment of the significance threshold. The way you describe your procedure, a sequential Bonferroni correction would fit. Strictly speaking the Bonferroni correction (and its variants) were all developed for independent hypotheses tests. You clearly don't have that, but what this means in practice is only that your correction will be a bit too strict. As you said the correlation should counteract the alpha error inflation, but it seems that people are generally just fine with being a bit too conservative.

Comment: Alternatively, you can consider a Bayesian approach, where the posterior distribution allows you to look at any range of effect size and gives you the likelihood for that. No multiple testing required --but this is then going in a different direction.